# Listbox Datatemplate update

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, listbox, datatemplate

I have a Windows Phone 7 App with Listbox. I have created my own template selector class, that select proper datatemplate based on number of items in binded object. It works fine. But what I need, and what doesnt work fine, is when i change number of items in binded object, to reload template selector and update templates based on actual number. 
For example: ListItems with property x > 9 have color red, when x =< 9, color is green. When i change this number with onpage button from 8 to 9 I need to change the color. And It doesnt work. Looks like template selector is called only on navigateTo event...
Help:)

Comment: Maybe you could try to invalidate the control and so force it to repaint itself.

Comment: I dont understand, the event that changes the value from 8 to 9 can also  update the template right? Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, I would recommend using a [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

However, you need to make sure that the property reflecting the number value, also is Observable. (ie. you need to call `OnPropertyChanged` from it's setter).

But a value converter like this, should do the trick:

```
public class IntToColorValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is int)
        {
            int number = (int)value;
            if (number < 9)
                return Colors.Green;
            else if (number > 9)
                return Colors.Red;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```